# How can I make xlab and ylab visible when using theme_wsj {ggthemes}?

Tags: r, ggplot2

You can see examples in [this page](https://github.com/jrnold/ggthemes#geoms).

Notice that in `theme_wsj` example, `xlab` and `ylab` do not appear.

Here's a non-ggthemes plot that includes labels:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) +
geom_point() +
xlab("Hello World: X axis") +
ylab("Hello World: Y axis")
```

But, when you add the `theme_wsj` theme, they disappear:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) +
geom_point() +
xlab("Hello World: X axis") +
ylab("Hello World: Y axis") +
theme_wsj()
```

Comment: Actually, this is a real question with insufficient examples.  I just edited it to demonstrate the problem.  @didzis-elferts solution fixes it nicely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look on source code of `theme_wsj()` you can see that axis titles are set as blank

```
theme_wsj<-function(base_size=12, color="brown", base_family="sans", title_family="Courier") {
    colorhex <- ggthemes_data$wsj$bg[color]
    (theme_foundation()
     + theme(
.....
      axis.title=element_blank()
....
```

So one solution to get `xlab` and `ylab` to be shown is to add new theme element

```
+theme_wsj()+theme(axis.title=element_text(size=12))
```